# finetune a model with LoRa, then load it in its vanilla architecture

Tags: openai-whisper, peft

I am following this [code](https://github.com/Vaibhavs10/fast-whisper-finetuning/blob/main/README.md) to finetune `openai-whisper` eith `LoRa`. The output is a `PeftModel` model. I want to load it (or do finetuning) in such a way so that I can get back the vanilla whisper architecture.

The steps of finetuning are

1.instantiate a base model.

```
model = WhisperForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("openai/whisper-tiny", load_in_8bit=False)
```

2.Create a configuration (LoraConfig) where you define LoRA-specific parameters.

```
config = LoraConfig(r=32, lora_alpha=64, target_modules=["q_proj", "v_proj"], lora_dropout=0.05, bias="none")
```

3.Wrap the base model with get_peft_model() to get a trainable PeftModel.

```
model = get_peft_model(model, config)
```

4.Train the PeftModel as you normally would train the base model.

```
trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
args=training_args,
model=model,
train_dataset=dataset_dict["train"],
eval_dataset=dataset_dict["test"],
data_collator=data_collator,
tokenizer=processor.feature_extractor,
callbacks=[SavePeftModelCallback],
)
model.config.use_cache = False  # silence the warnings. Please re-enable for inference!

trainer.train()
```

I save the model using `trainer.save_model(MODEL_SAVE_FOLDER_NAME)`. I load it as follows:

```
peft_model_id = "reach-vb/test" # Use the same model ID as before.
language = "en"
task = "transcribe"
peft_config = PeftConfig.from_pretrained(peft_model_id)
model = WhisperForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(
  peft_config.base_model_name_or_path, load_in_8bit=False, device_map="auto"
)

model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(model, peft_model_id)
```

Now this model is a `PeftModel` model and I can see its from architecture.

I want to load it (or do finetuning) in such a way so that I can get back the vanilla whisper architecture. (would be even better if its not the huggingface architecture but the actual openai-whisper's architecture).